# CiviEvent 4.7* Wordpress - calculated fees with default values doubled w/WP Plugin

Tags: wordpress, civievent

After setting up and configuring Civicrm 4.7.20 w/latest Wordpress (4.8.1 or so) I upgraded to 4.7.21 all seemed to go well.  Then I logged in and tried 'test drive' an Event, and 'live' registration. In 'live' mode, the default service fee I set up was doubled.   I created a test system locally and turned on debugging, tried Smarty debug and the relevant price set fields all looked correct. In NetBeans I checked the Register form after the setDefaults call, values were correct, but any price I set up with a 'default' was doubled by Calculate.tpl
I know this is very specific and I didn't expect to find a solution on stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem was due to a Wordpress plugin I set up called Inactive Logout (https://wordpress.org/plugins/inactive-logout/) caused the problem. Once I deactivated the plugin all worked well.
 Moral of the story: beware the smiling WP plugin, the javascript that bites, the session vars that snatch, beware the easy download and shun the frumious extension.
 On a serious note I think the plugin doubled the logged-in users but have to investigate.

It turned out the problem was caused by a call to wp_footer in src/inactive-logout-functions.php line 16, commenting-out that line fixed the problem and the inactive logout still works. wp-footer appends data to the /body tag